# Running script/plugin directly with server cron?

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, server

Just googled it & didn't get answer in first 10 pages - everything was about WP-cron.

**How to directly run plugin/PHP file with server-cron?**
Or do you always have to hook your plugin with WP-cron & then hook it with server cron?

There are 2 options in my server's cronjob panel: interval and command. Command is currently containg URL to WP-cron.

- Do I replace it with my plugin URL path?
- If that's the case, I imagine plugin doesn't have to be activated?

**Why I ask this?**
Server cron just activates WP-cron that checks if it has to run something. That means that those two crons & time when "check" occurs has to be syncronized if I want something to be precise. That doesn't sound very pleasant, especially if there was a way to directly hook my plugin to server cron. **All this also seems too risky to just try and see what happens.**

Comment: WP-cron is also launched when the website is browsed. what do you need when you speak about "something precise" ?

Comment: WP-cron is unfortunately not reliable enough. I already had bad experience with missed crons. I don't mean by precise that it has to happen with second or minute accuracy but I would like it to happen every **night** at same time. Bad thing about night is that there is not so many visitors but the good thing is that then nobody notices if you run something big - database cleaning or other big processes. Also server cron gives much more flexibility. It takes unnecessary coding again if you don't like WP default intervals (daily, hourly etc).

Comment: missed crons can occur when nobody browse the website but it will work better when a extern action launch the cron in addition, like a cron job of the server

Comment: Could not you use `curl` in your cron job to run a specific php script ?

Comment: @mmm What do you mean by better? If I could hook up action directly with server (which is super accurate) I wouldn't have to worry about that. **Also big pluss I read about: that one unfortunate visitor who activates WP-cron, gets a muuuch longer loading time (depends how big the action is ofcorse).**

Comment: @dvhh Is this server or operating system's specific command? I have to look into it. I have Apache and FreeBSD OP.

Comment: It might be possible that curl might not be installed, you still have the option to use either `wget` or `netcat` (`nc`), to query a specific page by url, although netcat requires you to write the HTTP request. could you check waht is installed on the server  (FreeBSD level)?

Comment: in the last version of WordPress, the cron jobs are run asynchronously. so the visitor who activate the cron will not see a difference

Comment: @dvhh I couldn't see curl in server info page but my host maybe just didn't include those details. If you're asking the version: **FreeBSD 9.3-STABLE**

Comment: I think that curl should be installed by default, why don't you try and see if the cron job has any effect ?

Comment: Im going to try it soon, first I need to take this code out of theme and make it as plugin. It might not happen today but I'll let you know in here. Thank you for your time! Cheers!

Comment: @dvhh I got it to work without commands `curl` or `wget`! Happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can launch the plugin action with the AJAX helper of WordPress like that

```
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_cleanDB", function () {
    // code to clean the DB
});
```

then in your server cron you can call this URL :
http://server/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=cleanDB

the command to call an URL depends of the hoster, it can be e.g. `wget` or `curl`

Comment: I imagine the right command comes before URL and there's a space between them? That seems like a reasonable approach indeed but I still have few more questions: **1)** If I use this add_action in plugin, does it have to be activated? **2)** This might seems like offtopic but if I wanted to add it to functions.php - it's starting to get pretty long, does functions.php gets loaded on every page load or just part-by-part if any action is called.

Comment: **1)** yes the plugin need to be activated to work **2)** yes the functions.php is loaded on every page, even in admin-ajax. but theme are made to just display the datas of your website and not to work with them. so the functions.php is not a good place for the code which will clean your DB

Comment: Thanks for the info, I appreciate it! How about register activation_hook? I've seen it beeing used in plugins.

Comment: That's weird, I just inserted direct url to that action & I even didn't need to use `wget` or `curl` - just works like that! Thanks, I learned a new trick from you. Cheers!